# all data in analytics in not loading wso2 3.0.0 analytics dashboard

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

```
listenerConfigurations:
    -
      id: "default"
      host: "localhost"
      port: 9091
    -
      id: "msf4j-https"
      host: "localhost"
      port: 9444
      scheme: https
      keyStoreFile: "${carbon.home}/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks"
      keyStorePassword: wso2carbon
      certPass: wso2carbon

  senderConfigurations:
    -
      id: "http-sender"

siddhi.stores.query.api:
  transportProperties:
    -
      name: "server.bootstrap.socket.timeout"
      value: 60
    -
      name: "client.bootstrap.socket.timeout"
      value: 60
    -
      name: "latency.metrics.enabled"
      value: true

  listenerConfigurations:
    -
      id: "default"
      host: "localhost"
      port: 7071
    -
      id: "msf4j-https"
      host: "localhost"
      port: 7444
      scheme: https
      keyStoreFile: "${carbon.home}/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks"
      keyStorePassword: wso2carbon
      certPass: wso2carbon
```

what should be value instead of localhost for the host, in wso2 3.0.0 analytics worker configuration, all other configurations are done by me but with distributed deployment, all data in analytics is not loading,
all other configurations are done by me correctly

Answer (score 0):

In API manager 3x versions, analytics stats are designed to show from the analytics dashboard which comes with the analytics components.

Hence, there will not be an external call goes to the publisher or devportal to extract the data.

Hence, the localhost will work without any issues.

Please do check whether you have configured the AM DB in the analytics node. it is fetching the data within the analytics since the AM DB is shared.

Otherwise, capture a HAR file or trace the network tab of the browser and check whether any API fetching calls are failing or relevant information are retrieved.

Thanks,
Dileepa